# Reset a high score in a Sprite Kit game using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to reset my high score in my Sprite Kit game, but am having some trouble.

Now, I'm able to reset the labels in the HUD back to zero, but when the game starts again the scores in the labels jump back up to where they were before because they are stored in NSUserDefaults.

I'm resetting the labels like so:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

   lblCoins.text = "0"
   lblScore.text = "0"

 }
```

I'm trying to reset NSUserDefaults like so:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(0, forKey: "highScore")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(0, forKey: "coins")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

I've tried placing this block of code everywhere in my game, but can't seem to reset the score. The score will only reset if I completely reset the app.

Here are some functions I've tried placing:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

   NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(0, forKey: "highScore")
   NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(0, forKey: "coins")
   NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
}
```

On GameOver:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

   ...

 case is GameOver:
    let newScene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene")
    newScene!.scaleMode = .AspectFill
  let reveal = SKTransition.flipHorizontalWithDuration(0.5)
  self.view?.presentScene(newScene!, transition: reveal)

  self.saveHighScore("com.prismstudios.jumpingcarl.leaderboard", score: GameState.sharedInstance.highScore)

   NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(0, forKey: "highScore")
   NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(0, forKey: "coins")
   NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

 default:
   break
 }
}
```

Here is where I'm adding the points in the GameScene:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

  GameState.sharedInstance.highScore += 10
  lblScore.text = String(format: "%d", GameState.sharedInstance.highScore)

  GameState.sharedInstance.coins += 1
  lblCoins.text = String(format: "%d", GameState.sharedInstance.coins)
}
```

The GameState class:

```
class GameState {
   var score: Int
   var highScore: Int
   var coins: Int

   init() {
     // Init
     score = 0
     highScore = 0
     coins = 0

    // Load game state
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    highScore = defaults.integerForKey("highScore")
    coins = defaults.integerForKey("coins")
  }

  func saveState() {
    // Update highScore if the current score is greater
    highScore = max(score, highScore)

    // Store in user defaults
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    defaults.setInteger(highScore, forKey: "highScore")
    defaults.setInteger(coins, forKey: "coins")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
  }

  class var sharedInstance: GameState {
    struct Singleton {
        static let instance = GameState()
    }

    return Singleton.instance
  }
}
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: What is in `saveHighScore` method?

Comment: @hannad I made a gist: https://gist.github.com/lumierephoto/828848d37cf0ba892620

Comment: Are you sure the block of code to reset the NSUserDefaults is being called? Also, is the score being shown in the labels retrieved from there?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's being called or not. All i know is that the highScore is not resetting.

Comment: @Paul the highscore is not resetting because you are not overwritting it. You are just inserting a "new one". (I wrote you an answer, maybe it helps you. - I had the same problem and wasted hours to figure this out)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I figured it out.

After, I post the score to Game Center, then I add `GameState.sharedInstance.highScore = 0`:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

 switch gameState.currentState {

   ...

  case is GameOver:
    let newScene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene")
    newScene!.scaleMode = .AspectFill
    let reveal = SKTransition.flipHorizontalWithDuration(0.5)
    self.view?.presentScene(newScene!, transition: reveal)

    // Save high score to Game Center
    self.saveHighScore("com.prismstudios.jumpingcarl.leaderboard", score: GameState.sharedInstance.highScore)

    // Reset score and coins collected back to zero
    GameState.sharedInstance.highScore = 0
    GameState.sharedInstance.coins = 0

    default:
    break
  }
}
```

I'm not really sure why it works this way and NSUserDefaults fails, but I know it has something to do with the fact that I have a GameState helper class.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reset everything try this:

```
    let defaults = `NSUserDefaults`.standardUserDefaults()
    let appDomain: NSString = NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleIdentifier!


    defaults.removePersistentDomainForName(appDomain as String)
```

If you just want to reset your highscore you have to choose the right "one". If you are making something like this:

```
defaults.setValue(123, forKey: "Highscore")
defaults.synchronize()
```

And then

```
defaults.setValue(0, forKey: "Highscore")
defaults.synchronize()
```

You have something like an array:

```
Highscore1 = defaults.objectForKey("Highscore")![0] as? Int //123
Highscore2 = defaults.objectForKey("Highscore")![1] as? Int //0
```

You are just adding more highscores... Try something like this:

```
 func resetHighscore(){

        let defaults = `NSUserDefaults`.standardUserDefaults()

        defaults.removeObjectForKey("Highscore")
        defaults.setValue(0, forKey: "Highscore")
        defaults.synchronize()

    }
```

Comment: So, where in a Sprite Kit game should I run `resetHighscore()` to reset NSUserDefaults? I've tried in the `didMoveToView` and the `GameOver` case. Still not working.

Comment: @Paul just put this:

`NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(0, forKey: "highScore")
   NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(0, forKey: "coins")
   NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()`

with that: 
       
`let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.removeObjectForKey("highScore")
        defaults.setValue(0, forKey: "highScore")
        defaults.synchronize()`

If it is not working, are you sure that the GameOver case is called?

Comment: You can easily check if it is called with two "prints". One print before reseting your HighScore and one after resetting ist.

Comment: I updated my question to include my GameScene and GameState relevant code.